# My time countdown script is working fine in Google Chrome but it appears Nan Nan when opened in other browser

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<? 
include("commonfile.php");
$start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$end = $_POST['date']." ".$_POST['time'];
if(isset($_POST['productid']) && $_POST['productid']!=""){
    $productid = $_POST['productid'];
    $expdata = getdata("SELECT expire_date,expire_time from tbl_listing_master WHERE listingid=".$productid." AND currentstatus=0");    
    $time_rs = mysql_fetch_array($expdata);
    $expdate = $time_rs[0];
    $exptime = $time_rs[1];
    $end = $expdate." ".$exptime;
}
$n = array("expdate" => $end); 
echo json_encode($n);  
?>
```

this is the version of count down that i am using
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
   Countdown for jQuery v1.6.0.

Comment: Please, improve your text. It's hard to understand your question with no more info and that piece of PHP at first line. Show more of your code.

Comment: You need to show you rendered JavaScript & HTML

Comment: If the problem is browser specific then we'll probably want to see the client side output of whatever you are producing rather than the server side code to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your date parsing (I grabbed this code from the link on your dup question).

```
function updateCountdown(el, date, time, productId) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../coding/fetch_time_forquery.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {date: date, time: time, productid: productId },
      success: function(data)
      {
        newYear = new Date (data.expdate);
         $(el).countdown({until:newYear} );
      }

    });
}
```

You need to parse the date here: `newYear = new Date (data.expdate);`, but the format coming back from your php is `2012-08-31 2:33:35`.. It would be easier if you just returned a timestamp.

To do this in PHP you need to convert `$end` to be a timestamp instead of a string:

```
$n = array("expdate" => strtotime($end) . '000' ); // add milliseconds
```

in js:

```
newYear = new Date ( parseInt( data.expdate, 10 ) );
```

should work

Comment: Its not working I am using keith wood jquery v1.6.0 and it appears Naan in other browser...

Comment: I understand the problem. The problem is this line: `newYear = new Date (data.expdate);` .. you need to give it a valid date to parse.. so either pass a timestamp with the milliseconds or use a [valid date string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) usable by Date.parse.